# Customer cannot login after magento upgrade from 1.7 to 1.9.1

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.9.1

I recently upgraded magento from 1.7 to 1.9.1. All the features seems to be working including added extensions.

When a customer is trying to login, it redirects it back to the login page with error.

```
Invalid login or password.
```

I tried adding formkey code to the login form but no success in logging in. I used both the formkey codes that I found posted by some users, which they say it works for lots of other users

```
    <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
```

and

```
    <input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(); ?>" />
```

Is this because password is stored in different format in Magento 1.9.1 than in Magento 1.7?

Anyone has any other solutions?

Comment: use same crypt for both version, do not change it. you can found this key in file [root]/app/etc/local.xml. line no around 34. make sure both are same

Comment: What Chirag suggested try that first even if that does not work ,can you write the full path of the phtml file where you added the form key?

Comment: I had copied local.xml from 1.7 to 1.9.1, so the crypt is same for both.
PHTML FILE: app/design/frontend/[package]/default/template/customer/form/mini.login.phtml
app/design/frontend/[package]/default/template/persistent/customer/form/login.phtml

Comment: Rather than updating your question with the solution, you should answer your own question and accept the answer. This helps others by easily identifying that the question has a working answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**
In my case, it was the encryption method. Previously, the Magento setup I had, used to have sha256 encryption rather than md5. FORMKEY should have worked I guess if I did not had this encryption. I just had to change

> app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Encryption.php

```
public function hash($data) {return md5($data);}
```

to

```
public function hash($data) {return hash('sha256', $data);}
```